# Access Subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, root, document

Here is my directory structure:

```
- parent
    - child-folder-1
         index.php
    - child-folder-2
         index.php
    .htaccess
```

I want that when I visit `example.com` it should load the `index.php` file from `child-folder-1` directory and when I hit `example.com/xyz` it should load the `index.php` from `child-folder-2`.

What should be the contents for my `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Is `abc.com` the only domain on your account? Or do you need to explicitly check the requested hostname? Do you have an existing `.htaccess` file? What have you tried? Presumably your document root is the "parent" directory in your _directory structure_, in which the `.htaccess` file is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `example.com` is the only domain that points to your account then you don't need to explicitly check for this in the rules, so you could do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ child-folder1/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^xyz$ child-folder2/index.php [L]
```

Note that if you have existing directives in your `.htaccess` file then the order of the directives can be important. These *rewrites* would need to come *after* any canonical redirects.